# Conditional Flask-WTF Forms Fields

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I would like to include or excluded form fields depending on the category they selected.

One way i was thinking of doing is like this.

```
if form.category.data == "retail":
    # return "Retail Form"
    form = RetailListingForm()
    return render_template('seller/seller_new_listing.html', form=form)
if form.category.data == "wholesale":
    # Return Wholesale
    form = WholeSaleListingForm()
    return render_template('seller/seller_new_listing.html', form=form)

if form.category.data == "wholesale-and-retail":
    # Return Both forms by inheritance
    return render_template('seller/seller_new_listing.html', form=form)
```

In the html.

```
{% if form == WholeSaleListingForm  %}
    {{render_field(form.whole_sale_price)}}
{% endif  %}
```

This does not work because if its not a whole sale form the `whole_sale_price` errors and the `RetailListingForm` How would you recommended i include forms while having it all in one template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add another variable that handles your form selection type, and then pass it into the `render_template` function:

```
if form.category.data == "retail":
    # return "Retail Form"
    type = 'retail'
    form = RetailListingForm()
    return render_template('seller/seller_new_listing.html', form=form, type=type)
elif form.category.data == "wholesale":
    # Return Wholesale
    type = 'wholesale'
    form = WholeSaleListingForm()
    return render_template('seller/seller_new_listing.html', form=form, type=type)
elif form.category.data == "wholesale-and-retail":
    # Return Both forms by inheritance
    return render_template('seller/seller_new_listing.html', form=form, type=None)
```

Then, in your template, just use evaluate with `type`:

```
{% if type == 'wholesale' %}
    {{ render_field(form.whole_sale_price) }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing it this way as well. Thank-you